# Python list assignment error but printing the correct result

Tags: python, list

I'm doing this question on leetcode, why am I printing the correct result, but not getting the correct answer in leetcode?
It seems if I do

```
nums[:]=list(endArray+frontArray)
```

Then it would work. I think it's some list assignment issue?
[image]

Comment: Please post the whole code here

Comment: your output is not equal to expected. list is sequential

Answer (score 1):

You've just discovered the difference between variables and their values. A variable in Python always *points to* a value. It references one but doesn't contain it.

```
nums = list(endArray+frontArray)
```

This snippet makes a new, unrelated list and assigns that list to `nums`. The old list is still out there in memory somewhere unmodified. You just made a new one and assigned it to a local variable that's about to get deleted anyway.

```
nums[:] = list(endArray+frontArray)
```

This is an assignment to *all positions* (`[:]`) of the current line. We're not making a new list; we're overwriting all of the values in the existing list. Anybody who held a reference to the previous list will see the changes in this case.